# Rest Web Service (Post) in eclipse not working

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, post, plsql

I need to create a Web Service that uses the Post method.

The programs i am using is:
**Plsql developer** - This is my database that I want to post data to.
**Eclipse** - This is the java program I am using to code my web services with.
**SoapUI** - This is the program I am using to deploy my rest method.

I tried a few Post Methods and they have all failed me.

```
public class AgentDAO {


public List<Agent> selectAgents() throws SQLException {

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;

    List<Agent> agents = new ArrayList<Agent>();

    String selectTableSQL = "SELECT * from AGENTS";

    try {

        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        statement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectTableSQL);


        System.out.println(selectTableSQL);

        // execute select SQL statement
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {

            Agent agent = new Agent();
            agent.setAgentId(rs.getBigDecimal("AGENT_ID"));
            agent.setName(rs.getString("FNAME"));
            agent.setLastName(rs.getString("LNAME"));
            agent.setEmail(rs.getString("EMAIL"));
            agent.setDepartment(rs.getString("DEPARTMENT"));
            agent.setCountry(rs.getString("COUNTRY"));

            agents.add(agent);

        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());


    } finally {

        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }

        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }

    }

    return agents;

}

public void updateAgent(Agent agent) throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("Method update");
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    String updateTableSQL = "UPDATE AGENTS" + " SET FNAME = ?, " + "  LNAME 
     = ?, " + "  DEPARTMENT = ?, "
            + "  EMAIL  = ?, " + "  COUNTRY = ? " + "  WHERE AGENT_ID = ?";

    try {

        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        statement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateTableSQL);
        statement.setString(1, agent.getName());
        statement.setString(2, agent.getLastName());
        statement.setString(3, agent.getDepartment());
        statement.setString(4, agent.getEmail());
        statement.setString(5, agent.getCountry());
        statement.setBigDecimal(6, agent.getAgentId());


        System.out.println(updateTableSQL);
        // execute update SQL statement
        statement.executeUpdate();


    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());


    } finally {

        if (statement != null) {
            try {
                statement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (dbConnection != null) {
            try {
                dbConnection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void deleteAgent(Agent agent) throws SQLException {

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;

    String deleteTableSQL = "DELETE AGENTS WHERE AGENT_ID = ?";

    try {

        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        statement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(deleteTableSQL);
        statement.setBigDecimal(1, agent.getAgentId());

        System.out.println(deleteTableSQL);

        // execute delete SQL statement
        statement.execute();

        System.out.println("Record is deleted from AGENTS table!");

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());


    } finally {

        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }

        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }

    }

}

public void insertAgent(Agent agent) throws SQLException {

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;

    String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO AGENTS" + "(AGENT_ID, FNAME, LNAME, DEPARTMENT, EMAIL, COUNTRY) "
            + "VALUES" + "(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    try {


        TimeZone testtime = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+2");
        TimeZone.setDefault(testtime);
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        statement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);

        statement.setBigDecimal(1, agent.getAgentId());
        statement.setString(2, agent.getName());
        statement.setString(3, agent.getLastName());
        statement.setString(4, agent.getDepartment());
        statement.setString(5, agent.getEmail());
        statement.setString(6, agent.getCountry());


        System.out.println(insertTableSQL);

        // execute insert SQL statement

        statement.executeUpdate();
        // logger.info("AgentDAO - END");
        System.out.println("Record is inserted into AGENTS table!");

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());


    } finally {

        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }

        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }

    }

}

private static Connection getDBConnection() {

    Connection dbConnection = null;

    try {

        Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

    try {

        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        return dbConnection;

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());


    }

    return dbConnection;

}

}
```

This is my code that selects, updates, deletes and adds data to my plsql database.

```
public class Agent {

private BigDecimal agentId;
private String name;
private String lastName;
private String department;
private String email;
private String country;

public BigDecimal getAgentId() {
    return agentId;
}
public void setAgentId(BigDecimal agentId) {
    this.agentId = agentId;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getDepartment() {
    return department;
}
public void setDepartment(String department) {
    this.department = department;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Agent [agentId=" + agentId + ", name=" + name + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", department=" + department
            + ", email=" + email + ", country=" + country + "]";
}

}
```

This is how my  model  looks like.
Now for the part where I am struggling. I have a get method that works really good but then..... the POST..........

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)

public List<Agent> selectAgents() throws SQLException {
    return agents.selectAgents();
}

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public String insertAgent(Agent agent) {


     try {
        agents.insertAgent(agent);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@GET
@Path("/{agentid}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public List<Agent> getAgent(@PathParam("agentid") BigDecimal id) {

    try {
        return agents.selectAgents();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

When I run my post method in SoapUI I get this error in the raw data file.

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>   Connection: close
>   Date: Wed, 11 Oct 2017 06:55:51 GMT
>   Content-Length: 11
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>   X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID: 4b097786-3b8a-40f3-83c6-c337eb9db63e-000042d8
>   X-ORACLE-DMS-RID: 0

Bad Request

So then I tried different POST methods for my different tables that I have and I got different errors.

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public String insertComment() {
    return "Post works!";
}
```

I wanted to see if I would actually get at least something back but then I got this back:

> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
>   Connection: close
>   Date: Wed, 11 Oct 2017 07:01:51 GMT
>   Content-Length: 15
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>   X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID: 4b097786-3b8a-40f3-83c6-c337eb9db63e-000042e0
>   X-ORACLE-DMS-RID: 0

Request failed.

Then I tried

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response insertCustomer(Customer customer) throws URISyntaxException
{
    if(customer == null){
        return Response.status(400).entity(" Insert details !!").build();
    }

    if(customer.getFname() == null) {
        return Response.status(400).entity("Enter First name !!").build();
    }

    return Response.created(new 
  URI("/customerid"+customer.getCustId())).build();
  }
```

And I got the error

> HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
>   Connection: close
>   Date: Wed, 11 Oct 2017 06:59:42 GMT
>   Content-Length: 22
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>   X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID: 4b097786-3b8a-40f3-83c6-c337eb9db63e-000042dd
>   X-ORACLE-DMS-RID: 0

Unsupported Media Type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
@POST
@Path("create2")
@Consumes("application/json")
public String create(Agent entity) throws SQLException {

    AgentDAO agents = new AgentDAO();
    agents.insertAgent(entity);
    return "Successfully created";
}
```